# Variance of Continuous RV

Tags: probability

Let $A$ be a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed between $-3$ and $5$. Let $$B=A^2$$

Find $E[B]$ and $Var[B]$. I find
$$E[B]=E[A^2]=\int_{-3}^{5} {a^2\over 8} da = {19 \over 3}$$
and $$Var[B]=Var[A^2]=E[A^4]-E[A^2]^2=\int_{-3}^{5}{a^4\over 8}da -\left({19\over 3}\right)^2=\left.{a^5\over 3}\right|_{-3}^{5} -\left({19 \over 3}\right)^2$$ 
$5^5$ would be really great number, I did a miscalculation or My Method of finding VAR is wrong itself?

Comment: No, your method is fine

Comment: Then how teacher expected us to calculate such thing ?

Comment: Usually in a course at this level if you write something down that can be plugged into a simple calculator you need not simplify it further. There are always exceptions of course.

Comment: Note: $\displaystyle \int_{-3}^5 \frac {a^4}{8}\operatorname d a = \frac {a^5}{40}\Big|_{a=-3}^{a=5}$